# Is impersonating moderators against the rules?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I just saw [this profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8415/badps-socketpuppet) and was wondering 1) if that's badp doing one of his weird experiments again? and 2) whether it is or isn't actually badp, is it ok for that account to exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that would be me helping testing one moderator toy. Well, it *would have* have been me, but I lost the cookies to the account, effectively locking myself out of it. I merged the account with mine, taking over ownership of that answer.

No, it is (generally) not okay to impersonate other users. That's why I chose the very clear usename of "badp's sockpuppet."

Comment: Why didn't you just choose a name like "Fred", which wouldn't have been associable with you in any way?

Comment: @GnomeSlice At most I would've chosen "Bob"

Comment: *twitch*